# How to update array with data from an axios fetch request and render using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I fetch a list of active tasks from Todoist

```
const [activeTasks, setActiveTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://api.todoist.com/rest/v1/tasks?project_id=111234345", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer xxxAuthorisationCodexxx",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => setActiveTasks(res.data));
  }, []);
```

Process the results.

```
const [allTasks, setAllTasks] = useState([]);  // flat list of all tasks
const [nestedAllTasks, setNestedAllTasks] = useState([]);  // Nested list of all tasks

useEffect(() => {
    let tasks = [];
    activeTasks.map((task) =>
       tasks.push({
         id: task.id,
         parent_id: task.parent_id,
         content: task.content,
         priority: task.priority,
         comments: [],
         complete: false,
       })
    );
    
    setAllTasks(tasks);
  }, [activeTasks, labels]);
```

I then try to iterate over `allTasks` and add comments, each comment needs a fetch request based on the task id, which I have encapsulated in the `getComments` function.

```
const getComments = useCallback(async (task_id) => {
    const comments = await axios.get(
      `https://api.todoist.com/rest/v1/comments?task_id=${task_id}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer xxxAuthorisationCodexxx",
        },
      }
    );
    return comments;
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    let tasks = [...allTasks];  // shallow copy allTasks
     const getAllComments = () => {
       tasks.map(async (task) => {  // loop over all tasks
         await getComments(task.id)  // get comments for specific task
           .then((res) => (task.comments = res.data))  // add to comments property
       });
     };

    getAllComments()
    
    setAllTasks(tasks);  // update allTasks with new array including comments
  }, [getComments, allTasks]);
```

I expected `allTasks` to now have a comments from the fetch request, i.e.

```
{
 id: 1,
 parent_id: undefined,
 content: "Some content",
 priority: 2,
 labels: ["thing", "other"],
 comments: [{id: 12, content: "comment1"}, {id: 22, content: "comment2"}]
 complete: false,
}
```

Render function as requested

```
return (
        <div>
            {nestedAllTasks.length !== 0 ? (
              nestedAllTasks.map((task) => {
                return <Task key={task.id} task={task} colours={colours} />;
              })
            ) : (
              <p>Loading active tasks...</p>
            )}
        </div>
      );
```

The Task component

```
export default function Task() {
  return (
    <div key={task.id}>  
      <div>{task.content}</div>
        <div>
          {task.comments
          ? task.comments.map((comment) => <div>{comment.content}</div>)
          : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I `console.log(allTasks)`, I sometimes get what I expect, but this never gets rendered on the screen.

Comment: Show us your `render()`

Comment: @k-wasilewski, render function added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You have used **then** with **await** in the last useEffect. This is not correct. You should save the returned value of await in a variable.

```
  tasks.map(async (task) => {  // loop over all tasks
         let  res = await getComments(task.id) 
         task.comments = res.data 
       });
     };
```

Comment: Making this changes means I can console log `allTasks` and get an array of tasks with comment data, but this does not get rendered on the screen! It's like it needs to be told to render after it gets the data somehow, but I thought that's what `useEffect` was for.